# Is it UB to access 'padded' bytes?

Tags: c++, alignment, language-lawyer

If I have an object like this one:

```
struct {
    uint32_t n;
    uint8_t c;
} blob {};
```

then there will be 3 'padded' bytes.

Is it UB to access the padded bytes? E.g:

```
uint8_t * data = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&blob);
std::cout << data[4] << data[5] << data[6] << data[7];
```

I first assumed this would probably be UB, but if that's true then a memcpy would be UB as well:

```
memcpy(buf, &blob, sizeof(blob));
```

My specific questions are:

- Is it UB to access padded bytes?
- If no, then does that mean the values are defined as well?

Comment: As this is a very rules-laywery question, I'm not sure what the final answer will be.  I suspect it will be defined (as long as uint8_t* is unsigned char*), but the initial values will be left unspecified, like any other member variable that is left uninitialized.  Now, if you want specification citations, I leave that to someone with more time to look it up :)

Comment: I'm assuming `uint32_t` is aligned to `sizeof(uint32_t)`.

Comment: @PeterG: `sizeof(blob)` is required by the standard to be at least 5. Since `uint8_t` exists, it follows that `CHAR_BIT == 8` and hence `sizeof(uint32_t) == 4`. It's then a matter of alignment whether `sizeof(blob)` is 5 or 8. A wilfully strange implementation is permitted to make it 6 or 7.

Comment: @PeterG. How can `sizeof(blob)` be 4 bytes if it contains a `uint32_t` and a `uint8_t`? I can see 5 bytes and I can see 8 bytes. But 4? How?

Comment: @SteveJessop I think he means that on a system where `4 + 1 = 4` you cannot expect anything to be well-defined.

Comment: @all Sorry for the confusion guys, I hallucinated `union` instead of `struct`.

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not UB to access padding when the entire object has been zero-initialised (the standard says in §8.5/5 that padding is initialised to 0-bits when objects are zero-initialised) or value-initialised and it is not a class with a user-defined constructor.

Comment: So if the object was not zero-initialized but the members were assigned then accessing the padded bytes *would* be UB? (and so would memcpy?)

Comment: @StackedCrooked if it's not initialised but members are assigned to, then you can copy the members but not the entire object.

Comment: @StackedCrooked: If it is not initialized, the same thing that happens for any other uninitialized piece of memory would happen here: if your program depends on the value of the uninitialized memory you have UB, if the value of that memory is irrelevant to your program, you don't have UB (i.e. `memcpy` is perfectly fine in as long as your program does not depend on the value of the fields in the padding). Uninitialized does not imply undefined behavior, there is no undefined behavior in `int main() {int a; int b=a; return 0; }`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas actually I'm pretty sure that example is undefined, no?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: in C++ your example `int b=a` is UB. 4.1/1, "if the object is uninitialized, a program that necessitates [an lvalue-to-rvalue] conversion has undeﬁned behavior."

Answer (score 0):

I think, under the right circumstances, you could end up with UB for this. What I'm thinking of is where you have memory with either ECC or Parity checking, where the ecc/parity bit(s) are set by writing to the memory. If a block of memory has not been used before [never been written to AT ALL], and you read the uninitialized bytes in the padding field, then it could lead to a ecc/parity error when the memory that hasn't ever been written is being read.

Of course, in such a system, you'd avoid a whole heap of pain by simply doing a "fill all memory" at some point during boot, since it would be illagel to do:

```
struct Blob 
{
    uint32_t n;
    uint8_t c;
};

Blob *b = malloc(sizeof(Blob)*10);

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   b[i].n = i;
   b[i].c = i;
 }


 ...

 Blob a[3];

 memcpy(a, &b[1], sizeof(a));    // Copies 3 * Blob objects, including padding.
```

Now, since not all bits of b[x] has been set, it may fail to copy the data in the memcpy, because of parity/ecc errors. That would be pretty bad. But at the same time, the compiler can't be forced to "set" all of the padding areas.

My conclusion is that this is UB, but it's unlikely to cause problems unless there are special circumstances. Certainly, you WILL see the above type of `memcpy` code in a lot of code.

Comment: Reading any uninitialised memory is UB, not just on weird systems.

Comment: Yes, and if you use a `malloc` that doesn't fill the allocated memory, it would be bad using `memcpy` to copy structures that you can't write every byte of. Yet, we see this sort of code quite regularly, don't you agree? It works, because nearly always, the memory is filled by the OS, either during boot, or later on during for example the OS phase of providing the memory to the application. But I'm sure it's UB to cover the case where the memory is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

In C it's is not undefined behavior.  The only time you get undefined behavior from accessing uninitialized stuff (such as the padding in objects), is when the object has automatic storage duration and NEVER HAS ITS ADDRESS taken:

> 6.3.2.1.2:
>   If
>   the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been
>   declared with the register storage class (never had its address taken), and that object
>   is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been
>   performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.

But in this case, you're taking the address (with the `&`), so the behavior is well defined (no error will occur), but you might get any random value.

In C++ all bets are off, as is usually the case.

Comment: As Steve Jessop mentioned, 4.1/1 says that if a program requires an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of an uninitialised object, then it is UB.

Comment: Ah, missed the C++ tag -- in C it is well defined.  The C++ spec is broken here.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not undefined behaviour, it's certainly implementation-defined. While the C++ standard won't guarantee much about what your program does, your system's ABI specification -- [SysV](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/) if you're using Linux -- will. I suspect that if you're mucking around in padding bits, you're probably interested more in how your program will behave on your system than in how it will behave on any arbitrary C++-conforming system.

Answer (score 0):

A POD struct will live in a contiguous block of memory of at least sizeof(struct) bytes (which includes any padding bytes). Accessing the padding bytes (if they exist) would be UB only if it was not first initialized.

```
memset(&s, 0, sizeof(s));
```

This would initialized all bytes, including the padding. After which reading from the padding would not be UB.

Of course, `memset()` is a C-ism and we'd never do that in C++, right?